# jQuery Cropper | getCroppedCanvas length is way more than image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I made an image uploader with cropper. The uploaded image is ajaxed using getCroppedCanvas (as a base64). 
The cropper has worked fine, with the file size being correct (I account for the * 3/4 equation when measuring the size of base64 files). 
The problem occured with a specific image that I tried to upload. The size of the image (when measuring the base64 length * 3/4) ends up being 1.4MB. 
The original image is only 200KB. And after I decode and save the base64 in PHP, the image ends up being it's normal size again.
So this image is showing a bigger size than it really is (in base64 format). This is a problem because I have a 1MB limit setup (which I had to temperarily disable to test this).

This is the image :
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-1kukj2g8cI8/VXvwoTo5u-I/AAAAAAAAP0o/I8vCHjoUC1w/s1600/ice-sheet-120509.jpg

Comment: I'd imagine the cropper's image manipulations generate a result with minimal or no compression. 1MB is a pretty tiny limit in a world where cellphones routinely make 6+MB photographs.

Comment: @ceejayoz But this only happens with this image. It is something weird going on the base64 encoding.

Comment: that image is highly compressed

Comment: @cmorrissey So, is there any way for me to get the compressed file size from php before saving the image?

Comment: you can use `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.7)` where `0.7` is the compression level so you can compress images to try to get them to your desired file size.

Comment: @cmorrissey Is .7 a good number. What if I go up to 1?

Comment: @cmorrissey I added that code, the file is the same size as before..Is there no way for my to check the size the file will be in php before saving it off? (base64 being inaccurate for testing the size)